# Lens for Olympus OM-D 10

Tags: lens, travel, olympus, street-photography, lens-recommendation

What single fixed lens for street photography and portraits (and travel photography) would you recommend?

I currently use the stock lens that came with the Olympus OM-D 10, and would like to use a general purpose single fixed lens for a long trip. Especially for portraits and street photography.

Thanks!

Comment: Once you narrow down your choices with information from the linked question above, if you're still left wondering, please do come back and ask about your specific deciding factors. (Note, though, that a "which should I buy?" or "which is better?" question will likely be closed.)